# matching file names (without extension) in two folders and write them in a new folder

Tags: bash

I have two folders dir1, dir2. 
dir1 contains all *.png files and
dir2 contains all *.mrc files.
dir1 has less number of files than dir2.

I know for sure that for each png file in dir1 there is a mrc file in dir2 with same name.
How can I create a folder that will contain only those mrc files having same name as png files?

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat inefficient, but if you know for sure that each png file has a corresponding mrc file, then all you really need to do is loop over the png files and replace the directory component and extension e.g.

```
for f in dir1/*.png; do echo cp "dir2/$(basename "$f" .png).mrc" newdir/; done
```

Ex. given

```
$ tree dir1 dir2
dir1
├── a.png
├── b.png
└── d.png
dir2
├── a.mrc
├── b.mrc
├── c.mrc
├── d.mrc
├── e.mrc
└── f.mrc

0 directories, 9 files
```

then

```
$ for f in dir1/*.png; do echo cp "dir2/$(basename "$f" .png).mrc" newdir/; done
cp dir2/a.mrc newdir/
cp dir2/b.mrc newdir/
cp dir2/d.mrc newdir/
```

*Remove the* `echo` *once you're satisfied it's doing what you want*